# Unread messages even though the message has been viewed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

Stackoverflow Careers sends an email when a candidate has replied to a message. Despite clicking on the link in the email, which opens up that message thread, and responding to the candidate, the conversation is still marked as unread.

I think that going through this work flow should mark the messages as read.

Comment: The general rule we use is: as soon as the message is opened in the browser, it should fire off a message read request.  I'll take a look and see if I can find anything.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  I have tried to view the page exactly as you said and various other ways with no luck.  If the site is still acting up, would you mind giving me the user id you are logged in as so I can test that specific account?  You can find that in the URL when you click on your name at the top.